# How can I access the Database field of a database context interface?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, onion-architecture

I'm using .NET Core 3.1. I have the following problem: I want to do a transaction in the Application layer. There I have a DbContext interface because I don't want to have access to the Infrastructure layer where I have the DbContext class. In other architectures I was able to access the Database field and therefore the Transaction because I was injecting the DbContext class. Now I'm injecting the DbContext interface I created and I don't know how to add the necessary fields that has as result the possible usage of Database field from the DbContext class.
Here is the Infrastructure layer DbContext.

```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long>, IApplicationDbContext
   {
        private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
        private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options, ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
            : base(options)
        {
            _currentUserService = currentUserService;
            _dateTime = dateTime;
        }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
   }
```

And here is the Application layer DbContext interface.

```
    public interface IApplicationDbContext
    {
       Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
       public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
   public class CityService
   {
      private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;
      public CityService(IApplicationDbContext context)
      {
         _context = context;
      }
   public Task AddAsync(City city, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
      using var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
      try
      {
         await _context.AddAsync(city, cancellationToken);
         await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
         await transaction.CommitAsync();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         await transaction.RollbackAsync();
      }
   }
   }
```

Comment: There are already multiple questions on topic: how to use transaction with EF... with answers .. search for: **unit of work**

Comment: On a side note you should probably be using `DbSet.Add` and not `AddAsync`. See also the documentation note: `"This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used."`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. In the interface I added the following field:

```
public DatabaseFacade Database { get; }
```

After that I used it in the way I desired in the last code section from my question. Everything works like a charm! I don't know if it is the best way to do this but it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

> ... how to have the possiblity to use transaction when using a DbContext interface.

If you want to use an interface then create and implement the appropriate method and call through.

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
   Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
   DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

   // added
   IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction();
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : ... IApplicationDbContext
{
    // added
    public IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        return _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea for my problem. This too is a very good solution but I didn't want to make it more abstract. Also, I added my answer here if you want to see how I've done it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add DatabaseFacade to the interface than you have access to the Infrastructure layer.

You can add BeginTransaction() to the interface and implement it to the class:

```
public interface IApplicationDbContext
{
     int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
     int SaveChanges();
     Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, 
     CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken());
     Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken calncellastionToken = new 
     CancellationToken());
     IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction();
     DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
   ApplicationRole, long>, IApplicationDbContext
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options, ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime; 
    }

    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

    public IDbContextTransaction BeginTransaction()
    {
        return Database.BeginTransaction();
    }
```

}